# Undefined variable: errors in laravel foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to retrieve data from database into my Laravel CRUD, but it says undefined variable in my view.

Here's the view frame.blade.php

```php
@foreach($mahasiswa as $mhs)
   <tr>
       <td>{{$mhs->id}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->nim}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->nama}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->alamat}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->fakultas}}</td>
       <td><a onclick="event.preventDefault();editmhsForm({{$mhs->id}});" href="#" class="edit open-modal" data-toggle="modal" value="{{$mhs->id}}"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
           <a onclick="event.preventDefault();deletemhsForm({{$mhs->id}});" href="#" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
       </td>
       </tr>
@endforeach
```

Here's the controller

```php
use App\Dashboard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $mhs = Dashboard::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);

    return view('frame')->with('frame', $mhs);
}
```

And here's the route

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'mahasiswa'], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'DashboardController@show',
        'as'   => 'mahasiswa.show',
    ]);

    Route::post('/dashboard/', [
        'uses' => 'DashboardController@store',
        'as'   => 'mahasiswa.store',
    ]);

    Route::put('/dashboard/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'DashboardController@update',
        'as'   => 'mahasiswa.update',
    ]);

    Route::delete('/dashboard/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'DashboardController@destroy',
        'as'   => 'mahasiswa.destroy',
    ]);
});
```

I keep getting "Undefined variable: mahasiswa" on my view

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: Use `return view('frame')->with('mahasiswa', $mhs);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a data called `frame` and trying to iterate over `$mahasiswa`, so either change your blade to this:

```
@foreach($frame as $mhs)
   <tr>
       <td>{{$mhs->id}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->nim}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->nama}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->alamat}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->fakultas}}</td>
       <td><a onclick="event.preventDefault();editmhsForm({{$mhs->id}});" href="#" class="edit open-modal" data-toggle="modal" value="{{$mhs->id}}"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
           <a onclick="event.preventDefault();deletemhsForm({{$mhs->id}});" href="#" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
       </td>
       </tr>
@endforeach
```

or in your controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $mhs = Dashboard::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);

    return view('frame')->with('mahasiswa', $mhs);
}
```

Comment: Also handle undefined variable by `@foreach($frame ?? [] as $mhs)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

First in the controller assign your DB query results to **$mahasiswa**:

```
use App\Dashboard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $mahasiswa = Dashboard::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);

    return view('frame', compact('mahasiswa'));
}
```

Then in the view:

```
@foreach($mahasiswa as $mhs)
   <tr>
       <td>{{$mhs->id}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->nim}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->nama}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->alamat}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->fakultas}}</td>
       <td><a onclick="event.preventDefault();editmhsForm({{$mhs->id}});" href="#" class="edit open-modal" data-toggle="modal" value="{{$mhs->id}}"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
           <a onclick="event.preventDefault();deletemhsForm({{$mhs->id}});" href="#" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
       </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

It will get rid of that error.

I used **return view('frame', compact('mahasiswa'));** i.e **compact** instead of **with**. I think it's a lot cleaner and less confusing for starters.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it can still work this way:

```
use App\Dashboard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $data['mahasiswa'] = Dashboard::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);

    return view('frame',$data);
}
```

view

```
@foreach($mahasiswa as $mhs)
   <tr>
       <td>{{$mhs->id}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->nim}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->nama}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->alamat}}</td>
       <td>{{$mhs->fakultas}}</td>
       <td><a onclick="event.preventDefault();editmhsForm({{$mhs->id}});" href="#" class="edit open-modal" data-toggle="modal" value="{{$mhs->id}}"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
           <a onclick="event.preventDefault();deletemhsForm({{$mhs->id}});" href="#" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
       </td>
       </tr>
@endforeach
```